# How to put $ symbol in HCONF config file?

Tags: scala, slick

I am using the slick of alpakka to config the database. I want to configure the slick config in runtime, for example:

For slick.jdbc.PostgresProfile$ section, how to put "$" in the config?

```
s"""
       |config {
       |  profile = "slick.jdbc.PostgresProfile$"
       |  db {
       |    dataSourceClass = "slick.jdbc.DriverDataSource"
       |    properties = {
       |      driver = "org.postgresql.Driver"
       |      url = "${dbUrl}"
       |      user = "${dbUser}"
       |      password = "${dbPassword}"
       |    }
       |  }
       |}
       |
     """.stripMargin
```

Comment: Note that this is not about syntax of the config file, it is about syntax of Scala formatting strings - the `$$` escape in the accepted answer is a Scala thing. In HOCON, which I believe this config file is written in, `$`s should be escaped with quotes (i.e. `key = "${some_value}"` will escape the substitution, while `key = ${some_value}` will perform it).

Comment: Yes. In my scenario,  "slick.jdbc.PostgresProfile$" is a class name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
profile = "slick.jdbc.PostgresProfile$$"
```